# using dependsOn property in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am deploying VNET before deploying other resources. It does deploy the first VNET template, but gives an error deploying others, as it says subnet is is provisioning state i.e. the resource is updating.

I am using nested templates and tried using dependsOn property in the ARM, although is not working. Is is possible to use it at the resource level?

```
"resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "vNet_ResourceUnit",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().name]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('vnetTemplateUrl')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "hyphenBasedPrefix": {
            "value": "[variables('hyphenBasedPrefix')]"
          },
          "baseTemplateUrl": {
            "value": "[parameters('baseTemplateUrl')]"
          },
          "vnetObject": {
            "value": "[variables('vnet')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiversion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "keyVault_resourceunit",
      "type": "microsoft.resources/deployments",
      "resourcegroup": "[resourcegroup().name]",
      "dependsOn": [
        ------
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "incremental",
        "templatelink": {
          "uri": "[variables('keyVaultTemplateUrl')]",
          "contentversion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "hyphenbasedprefix": {
            "value": "[variables('hyphenbasedprefix')]"
          },
          "basetemplateurl": {
            "value": "[parameters('basetemplateurl')]"
          },
          "keyvaultobject": {
            "value": "[variables('keyvault')]"
          },
          "vnetObject": {
            "value": "[variables('vnet')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

How can i use the dependsOn property here at resource level? I did try at the last template using :

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetName'))]"
```

But its not working. 
How can i use it in the 'keyVault_resourceunit' itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wait for the deployment to finish, not the resources inside the deployment (because they are in a different deployment, template doesnt know anything about them).

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'vNet_ResourceUnit')]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a resource id in the dependency, try using the name of the resource object i.e. the value "vNet_ResourceUnit" from line 3 of the code in your question.

```
"dependsOn": [
  "vNet_ResourceUnit"
]
```

The effect that has is to make the arm process wait until that resource deployment (named "vNet_ResourceUnit") has completely finished, before starting your keyVault_resourceunit deployment.